# Cereal downvotes

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

It would appear I have a serial downvoter, probably based on my comments at [Vector field on an odd sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370886/vector-field-on-an-odd-sphere)

Anything to be done?

How very odd. I put Cereal on purpose. I do not think it confuses the reader for any significant length of time.

Comment: I got a whole bunch too (due to the same thread), and suspended the offending user, but as far as I can tell, my attacker is not your attacker. I'll see if I can figure out anything else. But presumably the script will remove the votes soon.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, thanks for your help. My take is that there is quite a large base of users who believe people should get complete answers without doing any work. Interesting that both of ours stopped with activity called "Today" by the software, I think Greenwich Mean Time.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, perhaps a sockpuppet voting?

Comment: @Zevc FYI if someone serially down votes you, you should let another moderator handle the suspension.  Letting another moderator handle the decision to suspend removes any doubt that the suspension was done for the sake of retribution on your part.

Comment: See also: [When are serial downvotes classified as anomalous?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3068)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Most cases of cereal downvoting are crunched by our automatic script that milks them away within about 24 hours.

If someone is particularly persistent in breaking their voting fast in this manner, drop us a line via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page and we can investigate further.