# Enable FAQ sidebar on the meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

A little known feature of meta sites is that they can have a sidebar with a few most frequently asked questions:  for example, [Programmers Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) does. For a   description of how it works, see [FAQ sidebar for per site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240186).

I propose to enable this sidebar here. Hopefully, it will cut down on the number of questions that are asked only to be quickly closed as a duplicate. The [list of FAQ questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) includes several evergreen topics such as MathJax, contacting a user, accepting answers, non-English posts, etc.

---

While we are looking at the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions, I propose to add the  following frequently occurring topics to the tag, so that they show up in the aforementioned sidebar.

1. "Reopen/undelete this question": [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - ) [current version]](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) (maybe the "volume" thing can be dropped from this; I don't see a problem with just using this one from now on).
2. "I was serially downvoted, what to do?". The canonical reference is, apparently,  [Cereal downvotes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9179)
3. "My question doesn't get answers and it's been like 20 minutes, what to do?". The best reference I see is [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478)
4. Asking a proof-verification question: [Best way of asking "check my proof" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4597)

Comment: I think this is a good idea. I'd also add something about "Can we ask question of any mathematical level on this site?"

Comment: @Surb Do you mean [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22650), or something older?

Comment: Well I did not trust myself to propose something explicitly, but I noticed that this question is pretty recurrent. Examples: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4869/should-i-ask-stupid-questions?rq=1), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-dumb-questions?lq=1), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22577/is-this-website-useful-for-high-school-students), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/624/is-this-website-really-for-everyone?rq=1) and so on...

Comment: re 2 I think we should have something in the sidebar with a clear title. Besides the answer might not be sufficiently clear either. (Even discarding the plays on words.)

Comment: Related from Meta.Programmers.SE the [request that got it enabled on P.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6910/40980) (and that it took 4 months for it to get acted upon).

Comment: Since it just came up: the [relevance of seniority when deciding dupe-closure](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22668/duplication-policy-do-dates-matter).

Comment: Speaking of faq, maybe some items [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange) could be updated a bit. (Or at least links to some relevant posts could be added.) I have just removed mention of homework tag there. (This faq-list was recently mentioned in a comment to another question by quid. I have even forgotten that it exists.)

Comment: @quid The OP appears to have deleted his duplicate question about duplicate questions (huh... meta on meta). For non-10K users, the dupe target is/was [Original post marked as duplicate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/original-post-marked-as-duplicate). (Edit: I guess this isn't necessary since deleted dupes become redirects for low-rep users.)